# Como saber se um botão foi clicado? Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Já precisei em algumas ocasiões saber quando um botão foi clicado e não encontrei uma propriedade de forma nativa no C#/Xamarin. Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem acima temos um `Entry` com um `Text` (apenas pra exemplificar) escrito `Pesquisa...` por Defaut e com uma função `ToUpper` (pra deixar todo texto em letra maiúscula), se caso eu clique no botão `LIMPAR` eu já queria poder adicionar o texto `Pesquisa...` novamente, mas a função `ToUpper` força o texto a ficar `PESQUISA...`. Por isso pensei em fazer um `if` que fizesse o seguinte:

```
if (BotãoLimparPressionado = true)
{
   EntryPesquisar = "Pesquisa..."
}
else    //a função para os outros casos continuariam normais
{
   EntryPesquisar.ToUpper
}
```

Comment: Mas se eu estiver no botão atual colocando esse `if` não faz nenhum sentido.

Comment: Desculpe, mas é que achei autoexplicativa a pergunta, agora tentei melhorar, editei ela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você esteja desenvolvendo o visual via XAML...

No seu XAML utilize

```
<Button Clicked="OnClick">Button</Button>
```

E no seu codebehind

```
private bool BotaoClicado = false;

public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  BotaoClicado = true;
  // Aqui dentro você poem sua programação
}

private void OutroMetodo()
{
  if(BotaoClicado)
  {
    //Aqui você poem o que deve ser feito
  }
}
```

Comment: Eu estaria num outro evento chamando um `if` para saber se o botão foi clicado ou não, veja meu exemplo na pergunta feita.

Comment: Entendi errado, desculpe! Para isso, a sua própria pergunta se responde sozinha, para saber se o botão já foi clicado você deve criar uma variável para esse controle, verifique a edição da minha resposta.

Comment: Ao que tudo indica a variável funcionaria, mas será que não tem uma propriedade nativa do C#/Xamarin que pegaria essa informação de clique? Conhece?

Comment: Acredito que não exista nenhuma outra forma, se existir algo nativo eu desconheço

Comment: Awn, certo, agradeço portanto.